# XPath expression to filter incoming XML Documents

Tags: xpath, mule

I'm trying to use a "Choice" to direct XML documents based on part of their content.  But as I'm new to mule I'm struggeling to understand how to get the xpath expression to parse the incoming message.

As an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) I've set up this flow:

[image: simple flow with choice between two logs]

The "when" for each choice is set to

```
#[xpath('//foo/bar').text] == baz
```

and

```
#[xpath('//foo/bar').text] != baz`
```

respectively.

No Matter what I seem to try; it always gives a response to the client of:

```
Execution of the expression "xpath('//foo/bar').text] == baz" failed. (org.mule.api.expression.ExpressionRuntimeException). Message payload is of type: ContentLengthInputStream
```

Do I need to convert the input into something first? If so then what?  Or is there something else I should be doing to make this work?

---

**Edit**

Having checked the logs it seems that the error was the same as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25744541/mule-issue-more-than-one-jaxbcontext).  More than one instance of JAXB context.  I found two ways to solve this.

One was to refactor all our code to have only one instance of JAXB *(not easy and not preferable but it does fix the issue).*

The other was to stop using XPATH in EML.  Instead I've created a Java transformer which manually uses a Java Document Builder and XPATH objects to extract the information and place it in the registry.  This also worked.

Note we couldn't use `getPayloadAsString()` without hitting "More than one JAXB Context".  Don't ask me why mule needs a JAXB context to convert an input stream to a string.  So instead we placed a `Bytearray to String` transformer in the flow:

[image]

**If anyone has any good way to use xpath in eml when there are more than one JAXB contexts included then feel free to leave an answer**

Answer (score 0):

The MULE [documentation](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Mule+Expression+Language+MEL) shows examples like this:

```
<when expression="#[payload.getPurchaseType() == 'book']">
```

where the comparison operator and its second operand are all inside the `#[...]`. Have you tried that? E.g.

```
<when expression="#[xpath('//foo/bar').text == 'baz']">
```

Comment: ... and many other permutations besides.  It seems the output from mule is misleading and the logs say something different.